# Subclass of DatePicker with custom data

Tags: android

I want to select in a database of books a single section in a chapter in a book in a series.
I thought it would be easiest (and look nicest) to use the DatePicker design, and replace years with series, months with books, etc.

Is this possible to do by subclassing DatePicker, or do I have to design it from scratch?

This is kind of the modified DatePicker look I'm going for:

[image: Example]

(The blue dots are sections, and will have numbers on them; first chapter has for sections, the second has 5, third 3, etc.)

Comment: Visually i don't see a relation between a DatePicker dialog and your sketch, so i suggest using a custom layout and material design

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Date Pickers don't expose that level of customisation, they are designed and restricted to use exclusively with dates.

To get more insight you can always have a look into the source, which is open source: [MaterialDatePicker](https://www.github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fmaterial%2Fdatepicker%2FMaterialDatePicker.java).